# Migration python procject from ubuntu to ubuntu server

Tags: server, python

I have few days experience with ubuntu server and apologize for stupid questions.

I wrote python program wich work fine on Ubuntu 18.04LTS. Now i am trying to run the same program on UBUNTU SERVER.
Inside the scropt I have subprocess call like that:

```
subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "--", "bash", "-c", string_as_parameters ])
```

When I am trying to run on Ubuntu server I have error:

```
[Error2] No such file or directory: 'gnome-terminal'
```

If I want to run program on both server and normal ubuntu, how should I call subprocess?
If is not possible, how to change my code for ubuntu server?

Comment: Ubuntu-server is pure command-line interface, no graphical programs / GUI.Therefor gnome-terminal (or any other graphical programs) is not installed.

Comment: That I know now. How to resolve my problem? Should I call subprocess program as normal python program and make all prints to file? Is other way? Can I call new comand line interface?

Comment: I am not a python programmer, but isn't it possible to call and execute bash directly ?. without any need for grapichal support  Also that problem might better be asked in a programming forum - and with a more clear description on what you are trying to implement.

Comment: For Ubuntu Server,  simply omit the first two items of the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/16886597) - @SorenA Yes, it is. You would do `subprocess.call(["bash", "-c", string_as_parameters])`.

Comment: This call fixed my problem: subprocess.Popen(['python3', path_to_file, arg1, arg2], preexec_fn=os.setpgrp) . I could not use subprocess.call because i have 3 subprocesses in one script and first program are waiting for finising firs call.

Comment: we can close this question